# Does SNS HTTP/S delivery honor any HTTP codes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-sns

I created a test to fill my SNS dead letter queue to help me develop code to read from this queue.  Long story short, I thought an HTTP error would be easiest to simulate failures, but surprisingly, they seem to be counted as success.

In case I am doing it wrong and for the benefit of anyone else who wants to try this out, here is my methodology.  I created an HTTP/s endpoint specifically for this test using a bash one liner:

```
while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n" | nc -Nl 9078; echo "" && date; done
```

So far so good.  I decided that returning a 401 code might be easiest.  Capturing a 401 page output with netcat:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.21.0
Date: Wed, 01 Sep 2021 12:22:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 179
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted example.com"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I altered my one liner accordingly:

```
while true; do echo -e "$(cat 401error)\n" | nc -Nl 9078; echo "" && date; done
```

I verified that visiting this page in Firefox would pop up a password dialog.
Come test time, SNS blunders along and delivers the message without fear.  The message never appears in the DLQ:

```
POST /poot/testingevent HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: Notification
x-amz-sns-message-id: REDACTED
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: REDACTED
x-amz-sns-subscription-arn: REDACTED
x-amz-sns-rawdelivery: true
Content-Length: 24
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: example.com:9078
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

{"401 for sure man": 11}
Wed Sep  1 12:25:31 UTC 2021
```

Does anyone know? Nothing so far uncovered in duckduckgoing "http code" sns.  If I can capture some other codes (403,500,etc) using netcat, I thought it might be useful to know which, if any, are honored.

Answer (score 0):

Any status code outside of the range 200 - 499 will be considered as a failure and retried according to your retry policy as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html. Once the max number of retries has been exhausted, the message will be delivered to a DLQ if one is configured.

Comment: I feel like this answer isn't quite enough to give credit.  It was easy enough for me to just turn off the script to generate errors, but I would like to get a more comprehensive list along with the behaviors.  I am close to finishing a few projects where I might have time to do this work and get a list of code -> behavior

Comment: Sure, I've added some additional details to the answer. It seems like this is more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: That is good information, but I had it when I was setting up the DLQs.  Do you have a  link to a document that backs up the 200-499?  I was never able to find that when I was doing the testing originally.

Comment: for reference, bullet point no 5 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.prepare.html